# Last item hidden with float:left

Tags: html, css

I have a very weird problem, I use float left for a menu (nav items) and the last item is hidden!

```
<!-- NAV -->
<nav class="nav myClearfix" ng-controller="NavCtrl">


    <a id="home" class="active" href="#home" ng-click="menu='home'" ng-class="{active: menu=='home'}">
        <i class="icon-home fa fa-home"></i>
    </a>

    <div class="mySep"></div>

    <a id="lulu" href="#lulu" ng-click="menu='lulu'" ng-class="{active: menu=='lulu'}">
        <img src="img/nav/luluface.png" alt="lulu" class="animatedPerso infinite wobble"/>
    </a>

    <div class="mySep"></div>

    <a id="news" href="#news" ng-click="menu='news'" ng-class="{active: menu=='news'}">
        <i class="icon-news fa fa-bell"></i>
    </a>

    <div class="mySep"></div>

    <a id="about" href="#about" ng-click="menu='about'" ng-class="{active: menu=='about'}">
        WHERE I AAAAAAM ?
    </a>


</nav>
```

See it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/62Pqy/

I don't understand, when I replace `a #about` by `a #news`, `a #news` is displaying but not `a #about`, so the last item is always hidden in my code. Why? it's just links with `float:left` and `display block`, and mySep in float left.

Answer (score 3):

You're setting your `<a>` tags to be 25% of the width, but the separator `<div>` tags are `2px` each. So the sum of all 4 `<a>` tags plus the `<div>` tags is greater than 100%. That forces the last `<a>` tag to drop below the window.

Answer (score 1):

In your CSS change this

```
.nav div.mySep {
    width: 2px;
    height: 60px;
    float: left;
    background-color: #E0E0C7;
}
```

for this:

```
.nav div.mySep {
    width: 2px;
    height: 60px;
    display: inline;
    background-color: #E0E0C7;
}
```

Just this line:
    **display: inline;**
and the last element is shown.